# adding a knockout if statement in view page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I wanted to add an if statement using knockout in my view page to display an item or not and this is what i have but i am not sure if i have the proper syntax:

```
  <!--ko if: $idx.ViewModel.isGroup = false -->
    <span id="Reading" class="column_title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
    <!-- ko -->
```

In my javascript file i have:

```
$idx.GetGroups={
   ByTime: function(url){
     Ajax.Get({  
       ....
      $idx.ViewModel.isGroup = ko.observable(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("groupproject") > 0);
     });
   }
}
```

Is this the right syntax for checking knockout value in the view?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare to false, its a boolean expression like :

```
 <!--ko if: !$idx.ViewModel.isGroup() -->
    <span id="Reading" class="column_title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
 <!-- ko -->
```

In your case, use ifnot

```
 <!--ko ifnot: $idx.ViewModel.isGroup() -->
    <span id="Reading" class="column_title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
 <!-- ko -->
```

(http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html)

Comment: I am trying this but i am not getting the results i am not supposed to be seeing. I updated how my javascript looks maybe i need to call a higher level?

Comment: Did you check the value of isGroup ? Did you add the "`()`" ?

Comment: Maybe try to make it work with a "regular" binding first, using `data-bind` on an element

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem you can test the evaluated value... like below

```
<!--ko if: !$idx.ViewModel.isGroup() -->
  <span id="Reading" class="column_title">@ViewBag.Title</span>
<!-- ko -->
```

if you don't put the "()" you will converting a function in boolean...